# Android ImageView blurry?

Tags: android, imageview

I have an imageview in my app and I am loading in an image that is the same size as the imageview I have setup 144x144.

When I run the app the image is very blurry.

I have set scaleType to fitCenter, but no change.  Is there something I am doing wrong?

If I look at any image on a website thru the device the image is clean and crisp so I know it isn't the phone screen.

Comment: post the xml and what it look like

Comment: Be careful with the density.

Comment: **144x144** is the normal size for an **xxhdpi** launcher icon (so this one should have a density of **480 dpi**). Density **matters**, despite what someone thinks.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was the images were stored in the medium resolution folder. Copying it to the high resolution folder fixed the issue.