# How to prevent a drawable from becoming blurry?

Tags: android, drawable

When i copy-paste an image to the drawable file, i get one image with the original resolution. When i use the New--ImageAset way i get a lot of images for different screen densities but they are all blurry, even xxhdpi! How can i have the different densities inages without this problem?
Im surprise i didnt noticed it before!

I read this but it hasnt helped me
[Android ImageView blurry?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25174161/android-imageview-blurry)
http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Any advice am i doing it wrong?

**EDIT**

I tried the AndroidAssetStudio but it still happens

Before
[image]

After (xxhdpi)
[image]

Cant i get it to be the ldpi and then make it scale up from it or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your image in different resolutions using [Android Assets Studio](http://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-launcher.html). Then, copy paste the image to the respective folder. This will give you a proper image, without blur.

Comment: Is there a way of doing it in android? Or does people always do it outside?

Comment: There's an open question about this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28503229/fast-ways-to-import-drawables-in-android-studio. Personally, I always copy/paste the image as I suggested in my answer. This is redundant work, and Android Studio needs to make this process more effective. @qerahile

Comment: But short answer is No, there is no way. @qerahile

Comment: I see, maybe in the next API

Comment: One can only hope. If this answer was of help to you, please tick it as accepted. Happy coding! @qerahile

Comment: Is there no improvement at all? @qera

Comment: Marcus, the asset studio made my images blurry for the launcher icons...How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

There is a [plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7658-android-drawable-importer) exactly made for the same purpose. You can use that plugin to make different sizes of the same image. You have to copy/paste a single image in drawable folder. Then right click drawable folder and select 
NEW>Batch_Drawable_Import. Select the size for your image and it will itself make the other sized images for you.